# java scraping data hidden in html and script

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-scraping

I would like java to display a particular line of a webpage. This line is a src link to a jpg on a server. But  Jsoup methods or OpenStreamReader methods cannot get the line that is generated only when a pin on a map is pushed.
 Here is a site: 
https://webgispu.wigeogis.com/kunden/omvpetrom/client/map.php?BRAND=OMV&LNG=SI&CTRISO=SVN&MODE=NEXTDOOR&VEHICLE=CAR

which displays this data for one gass station at a time in a frame that opens only when you click on a pin in a map. What's more, src link to .jpg with a gas price changes every two hours. I would like to get my program to get to those jpg-s but I donno how. When I use OpenStremReader to get to the html of this site I cannot figure out where to next.
Here is a line of  code (it is an img tag)I am looking for( it is an eksample,' tmp2C31' changes every 2 hours):

'img src="https://webgispu.wigeogis.com/temp/tmp2C31.tmp.png" alt="" title="" style="margin-bottom:5px;display:block;" class="preisImageClass" '

Please have a look at the upper  link and sugest which classes and methods should I adopt in my program. I have already read about OCRs so no need to explain geting data from jpgs.

thanx

Comment: `"thanx for HELPING IN KEEPING GAS PRICES IN CHECK"` -- I'm more concerned with keeping StackOverflow question quality "in check".

Comment: But seriously, this and similar statements: `"feel free to brainstorm on whic classes and methods should I adopt in my program"`, suggest that your question is too broad. Better for you to search for and try solutions, and then if they don't work well, to ask a much more specific question, one showing your code attempt. Voting to close for being too broad.

Comment: I wil delete my post as i obviously do not meet standards to be a part of this comunity but please point me in the right direction,  as I have been loosing my self in scripts of the above site for 3 weeks now

Comment: Actually Carter's recommendation is a good one: If you're parsing HTML through Java, look at using an HTML parser such as JSoup. This will not help you parse javascript and other similar generated content however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code vil return a html.txt file:

```
public void htmlToTxt(String startSite) throws Exception {
    URL u = new URL(startSite);
    InputStream is = u.openStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("htmlž.txt"));
    String code = new String();
    while ((code = br.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(code);
        bw.newLine();
    }
    bw.close();
    br.close();
    isr.close();
    is.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TestOMV a = new TestOMV();
    a.htmlToTxt(
            "https://webgispu.wigeogis.com/kunden/omvpetrom/client/map.php?BRAND=OMV&LNG=SI&CTRISO=SVN&MODE=NEXTDOOR&VEHICLE=CAR");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a HTML parser. In my opinion, the best parser is [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

From the site:

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

With this, you can specify what you want to display on your program straight from the html document.

Comment: Tryed Jsoup also but no positive results. Maby sugest a path to jpg with jsoup methods. You have to have a look at a code of an upper link.